# What is the use of default in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, get, kibana

```
GET /product/default/_search
{
 "query":{
     "term":{
         "is_active":true      
       }         
    }
}
```

> I am new to elastic search can anyone tell me what is the use of this default keyword in get mapping

Answer (score 1):

That is the (now obsolete) "type" parameter. in earlier versions, you could store different types (like Classes in Java) in a single index. but since 7.x i think, the type is being removed and the recommendation is to keep "one type per index", meaning all documents in an index should have similar structure.

depending on the version of ES you are working on, you can remove the type (the word default in the url) and just write "/product/_search" and you will see that the JSON returning has the "_type" for each document as "_doc" or "default" if you indexed with that type in an older ES.